# Final score calculate in percentage

Tags: arithmetic, percentages

Hello I got all my marks for anthropology today. I want to what I got in total but can't calcute it. There are three categories : projects are $35\%$, the two midterms $20\%$ each, and the final is $25\%$.

There were five projects, I got $480$ out of $500$. First mid I got $61/100$; second one I got $54/100$ and for final I got $37.50/100$.

I want to know what percentage I got in total. 
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the projects, there were $35$ points available and you got $\frac {480}{500}$ of them, or $\frac {480}{500} \cdot 35$.  How many is that?  Go through the various pieces and add them up.

Answer (score 1):

$\left(\frac{480}{500}\times 35\right) + \left(\frac{61}{100}\times 20\right)+\left(\frac{54}{100}\times 20\right)+\left(\frac{37.50}{100}\times 25\right) $